# Prove that a sequence converges to x

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

I want to solve the following exercise:
$(X, t)$ an $N_1$ topological space, $A \subset X$. Let $x \in \partial A$. Is it the following statement true or false? “There exists some sequence $\langle x_n\rangle$ that converges to $x$ and such that $\forall n ∈ \Bbb N\implies x_n \not\in \text{cl}(A)$”. If the statement is true, prove it. If not, give a counterexample.
I know that $x ∈ ∂A$ means that $x ∈ \text{cl}(A) ∩ \text{cl}(A^c)$ but I don't know how to relate this with $N_1$ and then prove the convergence.

Comment: What's $N_1 $ ?

Comment: Definition: (X, t) topological space is N1 if every point has a countable local base.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: think of the case where $\operatorname{cl} A = X$ so it's impossible to pick a sequence from the outside.